# Playback of 'recorded' sounds

Tags: c#, winforms, bass.dll

I'm building a fairly simple sampler in C#. I've got the basic sound structure down (sounds pitched, stopping sounds mid play, etc). But my problem arises when I try to record and play the sounds the user inputs.
When recording, I save the sound into a dictionary with the starting time as the key (Class 'time' starts from 0), along with the length of the sound.
When playing back the recorded sound, I'm currently using a timer to simulate time in the system. I set the timer interval to the time difference between the current sound and the next sounds every time I play a sound.
It mostly starts out fine, but the sound usually goes completely out of sync, sounds are cut short or start too late, etc etc, I assume the problem is with my use of a timer, but I have no idea of another way of doing it.
I'm using Bass.Net for the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

What timers are you using? Most timers in .NET would be too inaccurate for this task, you should look into P/Invoking Multimedia Timers (see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework) for example) or building your own using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).